# Compare two Lists and pass to another

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two `List<Int64>` ListA contains 10 digits of integer value and ListB contains 6 digits of integer, I have to compare both lists and pass to another `List<int64>` if ListA contains 6 digits from ListB.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output? Have you made a start with this code yet, and can you [edit] your post with that code?

Comment: How would you do it without LINQ? Do you have code that attempts (and fails?) to achieve this? [Edit] your post to include it, it'll make your question much clearer. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know the difference between digit and number? Any number contains 1 ore more digits. The number `42` has the digits `4` and `2`. With that information, do you think you have to reword your question?

Comment: I understood the part where "if all the digits in listB are present in list A" but the "pass to another list" part doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listA = new List<long>
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    };
    var listB = new List<long>
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    };

    bool doesListBContainListA = listA.All(numA => listB.Contains(numA));
    var listNew = new List<long>();
    if (doesListBContainListA)
    {
        listNew.AddRange(listA);
        listNew.AddRange(listB);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", listNew));
}
```

The above code will compare if all digits/numbers from listA are contained in listB and if they are they will be added to the new list.

P.S. `long` is the same as `Int64`